# Finding $E(X^k)$ given $X$ ~ $Beta(\alpha, \beta)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value

I have tried finding the value of $E(X^k)$ given that $X$ ~ $Beta(\alpha, \beta)$ and got stuck.

Here were my steps:

$$E(X^k)= \int_{0}^{1}  x^k \frac{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha) + \Gamma(\beta)}x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}dx$$
$$= \frac{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)  \Gamma(\beta)} \int_{0}^{1}  x^{\alpha + k -1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}dx$$

What can I do now? I was thinking about possibly rewriting $x^{\alpha + k -1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}$ in terms of $\frac{\Gamma(\alpha +k + \beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha+k)  \Gamma(\beta)}$, but I don't know how to do so.

Comment: In the denominator of the fractions involving the gamma function, the plus sign should be multiplication.

Comment: The idea in your last sentence is good. Think about how the PDF of $\text{Beta}(\alpha+k, \beta)$ must integrate to $1$, to help you rewrite the integral in your last step.

Comment: @angryavian Thanks for pointing that out, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
& = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)  \Gamma(\beta)} \int_{0}^{1}  x^{\alpha + k -1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}dx\\
&= \frac{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)  \Gamma(\beta)} 
\frac{\Gamma(\alpha + k) \Gamma( \beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha + k + \beta)} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\Gamma(\alpha + k + \beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha + k)  \Gamma(\beta)}  x^{\alpha + k -1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}dx\\
&= \frac{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)}  
\frac{\Gamma(\alpha + k)}{\Gamma(\alpha + k + \beta)}
\end{align}
Next, you can use the properties of Gamma function (e.g., $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$) in order to further simplify it...